# Powershell SSH Tunnel closes unexpectedly

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a powershell script that keeps closing ```ssh jumpbox_user@jumpbox_ip -p 22 -L port:server_address:port -i '~/.ssh/id_rsa' -N

The issue I have is that the tunnel will start but will then, randomly, it will close.  I have this issue no matter how I start the SSH tunnel.  I get the feeling that it has something to do, potentially, with my home internet?  I don't seem to have this issue at work or at other locations.  I've purchased a new router and a new modem to no effect, is there a way to check what is going wrong???